# FS0010: Incomplete structured construct when compiling AssemblyInfo.fs

Tags: f#

I am trying to build an F# project on TeamCity. Unfortunately the build agent does not have F# installed so I have added the FSharp.Compiler.Tools nuget package to my project.

When teamcity tries to build my project I get the following error (on a brand new project created from the visual studio class library template).

```
[Fsc] Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 4.1
[15:12:00][Fsc] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.
[15:12:02][Fsc] 
[15:12:02][Fsc] C:\TeamCity\work\3c40581f0aabd3be\Source\MyProject\AssemblyInfo.fs(43, 1): error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in definition
[15:12:03][Step 8/21] Error message is logged
```

The project builds fine locally, both in VS2017 and using MSBuild from the command prompt.

Is there any way to fix this? I don't have access to install F# on the build agent.

Edit: This is the contents of AssemblyInfo.fs:
    namespace MyProject.AssemblyInfo

```
open System.Reflection
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[<assembly: AssemblyTitle("MyProject")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyDescription("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyCompany("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyProduct("MyProject")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © 2017")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyCulture("")>]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[<assembly: ComVisible(false)>]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[<assembly: Guid("7a1189cf-d923-4367-991c-d95b1f045712")>]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
// 
//       Major Version
//       Minor Version 
//       Build Number
//       Revision
// 
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [<assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")>]
[<assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")>]

do
    ()
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `C:\TeamCity\work\3c40581f0aabd3be\Source\MyProject\AssemblyInfo.fs`? Especially the lines around line 43, say lines 35-50 or so. That might help us figure out what part of the file the compiler thinks is an "Incomplete structured construct". Also, if the version of that file on TeamCity is different than what gets produced when you build locally, that would be useful data too, so let us know what your `AssemblyInfo.fs` file looks like after a local build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so it seems GitVersion was being called on the teamcity agent and was appending an `AssemblyInformationalVersion` attribute to the end of `AssemblyInfo.fs` (after the `do ()`). Adding an empty `AssemblyInformationalVersion` above the `do ()` block fixed the issue: gitversion then modified the value of the existing attribute instead of adding a new one.